# regex exact match the string

Tags: java, regex

I have below string which I split using regex and   get id,id,roduct_clinical_studies__rimr,product__rim,product__v in an array.
This works for most of the cases. But for below string since clinical contains IN it fails.How can I do an exact match of IN/SELECT etc

```
 id IN (SELECT id FROM  product_clinical_studies__rimr  WHERE product__rim CONTAINS {{this.product__v}})


String[] parseString(String filterInString) {
    return filterInString.replaceAll("(?i)CONTAINS|IN|SELECT|FROM|WHERE|(this\\.)|[(){}=,]|(\\s{2,})", " ").
            replaceAll("\\s+", " ").split("\\s");
}
```

Comment: What is before or after each keyword?  Spaces, start of a line, end of a line? other text?  Can you assume "IN" would be surrounded by whitespace as in ![A-Za-z0-9] and other syntax symbols? As in "whole words"?

Comment: You could put a space or a word-boundary (`\b`) before and after each term.

Comment: why do we need ?:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either get rid of the `(?i)` or add a word boundary around
the literals

`(?i)\b(?:CONTAINS|IN|SELECT|FROM|WHERE)\b|(this\.)|[(){}=,]|‌​(\s{2,})`

If you need to match `keyword/keyword/../..` runs , this probably works
as well

`(?i)\b(?:CONTAINS|IN|SELECT|FROM|WHERE)(?:/(?:CONTAINS|IN|SE‌​LECT|FROM|WHERE))*\b‌​|(this\.)|[(){}=,]|(‌​\s{2,})`

Expanded

```
    (?i)
    \b 
    (?:
         CONTAINS
      |  IN
      |  SELECT
      |  FROM
      |  WHERE
    )
    (?:
         /
         (?:
              CONTAINS
           |  IN
           |  SELECT
           |  FROM
           |  WHERE
         )
    )*
    \b 
 |  ( this\. )                    # (1)
 |  [(){}=,] 
 |  ( \s{2,} )                    # (2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't identify by whitespace, then run this as two passes.  First pass with all unique objects, second pass for just "IN".